# How can I specifically embed different Elm module at scope of different view?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elm

Now I can only add the embed in app.js and it’s global.
But if I add
    Elm.MainApp.embed([target div])
in an eex template's script tag,
it says Elm is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out:

Step 1:
in app.js:
add this in javascripts block:

```
joinTo: "js/whatever.js"
```

(the file name of the js file you create in static directory)
and this in modules.autoRequire block:

```
js/whatever.js": ["web/static/js/whatever"]
```

Step 2:
Embed whatever Elm module you want in whatever.js

Step 3:
Create a plug for this in your router
like this:

```
pipeline :whatever_layout do
   plug :put_layout, {NameOfYouPhoenixApp.LayoutView, :whatever}
end
```

and add it in the list as second argument of the pipe_through function in the target scope
like this:

```
scope "/whatever", LicenseBoss do
   pipe_through [:browser, :whatever_layout]
   get "/", WhateverController, :index
end
```